# How do I calculate total number of unique values in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
>frame

  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  F  F  F  F
2  C  C  C  C
3  D  D  D  D
4 A# A# A# A#
```

When I run `unique(c(frame))` I get a vector of the four unique values, "F", "C", "D", "A#". However, if I run `length(unique(c(frame)))`, I get a length of 1. So I'm looking for a way to get the total number of unique values in a dataframe, and also in a subset of the dataframe.

Comment: Try `length(unique(unlist(df)))`

Comment: Worked great. Any idea why using c() didn't work but unlist() did?

Comment: It's because `unique(c(frame))` is a list of one element

Comment: `data.frame`s are actually `list`s of vectors behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @DatamineR:

```
length(unique(unlist(df)))
```

Answer (score -3):

I was struggling with the same problem as you but for Python. On it, I figured out how it works and it looks like this: len(df['column'].unique())

Comment: Well, the principle works the same way. I was about to ask a very similar question and the first 'similar question' that appeared was this. Then I remembered to use the len function. For those struggling with the same thing, I think my code could find use to them. Especially since the unique function is different in R as well.

Comment: Questions on SO are generally about a specific language, so an answer in Python to a question about R isn't going to be considered useful here

Comment: It's tagged R, and the code in the question is R, not Python. There's been lots of [discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290046/5325862) where the consensus is that in most cases answering a question about one language with another isn't useful. It's a perfectly fine answer to a similar question about Python